# Split a file by line and have control over resulting files extension

Tags: shell, filenames, split

There is a standard command for file splitting - `split`.

For example, if I want to split a `words` file in several chunks of 10000 lines, I can use:

```
split -dl 10000 words wrd
```

It would generate several files of the form `wrd.01`, `wrd.02` and so on.

But I want to have a specific extension for those files - for example, I want to get `wtd.01.txt`, `wrd.02.txt` files.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

With `gnu split`'s more [recent](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2012-02/msg00106.html) versions (`≥ 8.16`), one can use the `--additional-suffix` switch to have control over the resulting extension. From `man split`:

```
--additional-suffix=SUFFIX
              append an additional SUFFIX to file names.
```

so when using that option:

```bash
split -dl 10000 --additional-suffix=.txt words wrd
```

the resulting pieces will automatically end in `.txt`:

```
wrd00.txt
wrd01.txt
.........
```

Comment: Not working on mac

Comment: I love your sarcasm. I am a unix n00b from the Apple world. I am using OS X Yosemite and I just didn't want others to crash and burn like I did. I tested and reviewed at the docs and we don't have this parameter. I might have missed something. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/split.1.html

Comment: @swiftshokunin - my answer pertains to `gnu split`, part of `gnu coreutils`. It is also available on OSX if you install `coreutils` via `homebrew` but note that by default, on OSX, the `gnu` utilities have a `g` prepended to their name (e.g. `gstat` instead of `stat`) so you invoke it as `gsplit` (or alter the PATH as per the guide [here](https://coderwall.com/p/2khjya/install-100-core-cli-utilities-with-1-command) if you want to use it as `split` over the OSX `split`). HTH.

Comment: Nice answer. on OS X, use `gsplit` to get the numeric suffixes (-d) to work.

Comment: wow, i had no idea that there is gsplit - it's probably from coreutils mentioned above and it does have --additional-suffix. Thanks to everyone commenting this solution :)

Comment: @don_crissti Can we split the file with a custom numeric start. i.e `wrd05.txt`. It should start with the number `5` or `7`. Is this possible?

Comment: @Hussain7 -sure, just use `--numeric-suffixes=START` instead of `-d`  e.g with OPs code you'd run `split -l 100 --numeric-suffixes=05  --additional-suffix=.txt words wrd` to have it start at `05`... (assuming `gnu split` here)

Answer (score 22):

Such tasks are best managed with the shell.  Use split and then write a simple loop to rename the files.  E.g.

```
for file in wrd.*
do
    mv "$file" "$file.txt"
done
```

would rename your wrd.01, wrd.02, etc. files so they all have a .txt extension.

Comment: That's quite obvious, but it would break the conciseness of bash script.

Comment: The Unix philosophy is to provide you with a set of simple tools that you then combine to do a job. The "conciseness of the bash script" was not a stated requirement in your question.

Comment: I agree, but there are different combinations of simple tools out there, and some do job better. I just hoped that there was a good combination that could do this job better that a 5-line long split with file renaming.

Comment: Just a personal obversation: When you actually get both versions to do the same thing with similar var names... `awk` 79 chars, `split+mv` 78 chars       - - - - `awk '{f="wrd." sprintf("%03d",int((NR-1)/10000)) ".txt"; print >> f}' inputfile`       - - - - `split -dl10000 -a3 inputfile wrd.; for f in wrd.???; do mv "$f" "$f".txt; done`

Comment: PS:  the `split+mv` combo is more that **6 times faster** than `awk` (approx *3s* vs *18s*) for a 10 million line input file (75 MB)... the text in each line was its own line-number... Thanks for re-stating  the "obvious" :)

Comment: PPS: I've just been checking this out a bit further. The speed-difference is related to the number of files created vs the number of formatting and arithmetic calculations awk does for each and every line regardless of the number of output files... Using the same input file as the above example: When there are *100 times fewer* files, `split + mv` is **75** times faster than `awk`: When there are *100 times more* files, `split + mv` is **1.5** times faster than `awk`.  So, for me, this `split + mv` method wins, hands down. It is as consice (arguably moreso), and is faster than `awk`.

Comment: if you're concerned about it being 5 lines long, try this instead: `for file in wrd.*; do mv "$file" "$file.txt"; done` :)

Answer (score 14):

Not with `split`, but you can easily rename them afterwards, or you can do it in `awk`:

```
awk '{filename = "wrd." int((NR-1)/10000) ".txt"; print >> filename}' inputfile
```

Comment: Looks good - but does not work. In your form, complains about "expression for `>>' redirection has null string value", and if "file" is "changed" to "filename", outputs files of the form wrd.{file number}.{line number}.txt (quite a lot of them :)

Comment: @Rogach Sorry, I hadn't tested it, so I forgot awk doesn't do integer division. I've tested this one.