# naming split files using split command

Tags: shell-script, shell

I am writing a shell script where I am reading all the files in a directory, performing some criteria checks and splitting certain files on number of records (lines)

I want to split file abc.txt as abc(AA or 01).txt
(I don't mind anything as long as it begins with abc and ends in .txt)

Is there a simple way to do this ?

I am using split command:

```
split -l $line_count $file $????
```

I am confused what should be in place of ????

I am open to other methods too but I would prefer to just change the ??? as the other parts of the script is ready.

Many Thanks

Comment: Check this question [Split a file by line and have control over resulting files extension](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32626/split-a-file-by-line-and-have-control-over-resulting-files-extension)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
split -l 5 --additional-suffix=.txt abc.txt abc
```

Or, if you want numbers in place of letters:

```
split -l 5 -d --additional-suffix=.txt abc.txt abc
```

The `abc` that we added after the file names serves as the *prefix*.

Because you wanted `.txt` as a suffix, we added the option `--additional-suffix=.txt`.

The optional `-d` tells `split` to use numbers instead of letters.

#### Example

Let's start with a directory with one file:

```
$ ls
abc.txt
```

Now, let's split that file:

```
$ split -l 5 -d --additional-suffix=.txt abc.txt abc
$ ls
abc00.txt  abc01.txt  abc02.txt  abc03.txt  abc.txt
```

#### Work-around 1: using shell

Current versions of GNU split support the `--additional-suffix` option and `split` is part of GNU coreutils.  That means that this option will be eventually be available on all linux systems.

For systems that currently lack it, one work around is to rename the files after `split` creates them.  For example:

```
$ split -l 5 -d abc.txt abc
$ for f in ./abc??; do mv "$f" "$f.txt"; done
$ ls
abc00.txt  abc01.txt  abc02.txt  abc03.txt  abc.txt
```

The above assumes that the default suffix length of 2 applies.  If not, change the number of `?` to match the suffix length that you are using.  For example, if you are using a suffix length of 5:

```
$ split -l 5 -a 5 -d abc.txt abc
$ for f in ./abc?????; do mv "$f" "$f.txt"; done
$ ls
abc00000.txt  abc00001.txt  abc00002.txt  abc00003.txt  abc.txt
```

#### Work-around 2: using awk

Here, the option `l` specifies the number of lines to include in each splitted file and `d` specifies the number of digits to use in the splitted files name.  Make sure that `d` is large enough.

```
$ awk -v l=5 -v d=2 '{n="0000" int((NR-1)/l); f="abc" substr(n,length(n)+1-d) ".txt"; if (f!=old) close(old); old=f; print >f}' abc.txt
$ ls
abc00.txt  abc01.txt  abc02.txt  abc03.txt  abc.txt
```

Comment: This only applies to certain versions of `GNU split` so it may be distro specific.  RHEL 6.7 for example does not have this option.

Comment: @MikeA OK.  Thanks for that info.  I just checked with the GNU website and [GNU split](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#split-invocation) does include the `--additional-suffix` option and `split` is part of  coreutils.  So, if RHEL doesn't have it yet, it will soon.

Comment: Hopefully, it's a very nice and needed option. ;-)

Comment: @John1024 It didnt work for me.  unrecognized option '--additional-suffix=.txt'

Comment: perhaps like @MikeA mentioned, it is not available for all versions

Comment: @kpython I just updated the answer with a simple work-around.  By the way, what OS are you on?

Comment: @John1024 I am on Linux - writing ksh script