# how to give custom filenames when executing split command in unix?

Tags: command, split

Is there a way to give custom filenames for split command?
I am splitting a file that is 100GB into chunks of 128MB.
Here is what I am doing

`split -b 128000k mydata.csv`.

This creates files with following names `xaa,xab,xac,..` etc.
I am wondering if it is possible to have custom names like
`mydata_0.csv`, `mydata_1.csv` for each of the splits.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, with GNU `split` you can achieve this:

```
split -d -a3 -b 128M --additional-suffix=.csv mydata.csv mydata_
```

Explanation:

- `-d -a3`: use a numerical index with 3 digits
- `-b 128M`: split in 128 MB chunks
- `--additional-suffix=.csv`: add a `.csv` extension
- the trailing `mydata_` is the prefix

Comment: in centos, I get `split: unrecognized option '--additional-suffix=.csv'`

Comment: @brainstorm The option was added to GNU `split` in 2012. `split --version` yields me 8.21. If your version is not GNU or too old, see [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32630/203203)