# split file into chunks including more lines in the first piece

Tags: text-processing, split

I am trying to separate a large file with 4100 rows.
Separating 6 rows of numbers as file and other lines need to follow as 4 rows of number as file.Please consider the below.

How can I write a bash script?

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with `awk`:

```
awk '{if (NR>6){if ((NR-6)%4==1){++c}} else {c=1}};{print >"file"c".las"}' infile
```

On a `gnu` setup and with a relatively recent version `split` [which allows you to add a suffix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74166) you could also do something like:

```
{ printf %s\\n\\n; cat infile; } | split -d -l 4 --additional-suffix='.las' - file
( set ./*.las
sed '1d
s/\\/&&/g
2c\
1i\\
3s/$/\\/' "$1" | sed -f - -i "$2"
rm -f "$1" )
```

that is, print two empty lines and then the file, splitting the combined output into pieces of four lines, inserting the first two lines from the original input via `sed` (after escaping backslashes - if any) into the second piece and finally removing the first piece. Though keep in mind this will zero-pad the chunk names so you'll end up with `file0001.las` etc

Answer (score 1):

The following command will split as described presuming that the file is to be split every four lines.  The output files will be named e. g. `output00`, `output01`, and so forth.  You can then rename all `output*` files to tack the `.las` suffix to the end and, if desired, strip the leading zeroes.

```
split -l4 -d ./input_file output
```

Comment: Thanks for comments. I need to split first 6 lines and then every 5 lines.

Comment: `head -n1 input_file  > output-01; tail -n+2 input_file | split -l5 -d output`

Comment: error: split: cannot open ‘output’ for reading: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

```
csplit -s -k -f file. inoutfile '/^/+6' '/^/+4' '{*}'
```

Comment: this format does not work well.

Comment: error: csplit: ‘%^3%’: match not found

Comment: I have placed a new command.