# bash script: a more elegant way to perform these operations:

Tags: shell-script, files, split, 7z

I have these three files:

file.txt.7z = 5.4GB
file-1.txt.7z = 251M
file-2.txt.7z = 7.7M

And they are the only files in a directory:

```
$ tree
.
├── file.txt.7z
├── file-1.txt.7z
└── file-2.txt.7z
```

I want to

- unzip the files
- combine them into one file
- split that combined file into files of 500,000 lines
- have as a result a number of files with a ".txt" extention

Right now I am achieving it this way:

```
p7zip -d "*.txt.7z"
cat file-1.txt >> file.txt
rm file-1.txt
cat file-2.txt >> file.txt
rm file-2.txt
split -l 500000 file.txt
for f in *; do mv "$f" "$f.txt"; done
```

How could I achieve this in a more elegant way?

Comment: Streamed archive format is more useful here

Answer (score 3):

**`7za`** + **`split`** solution (single pipeline):

```
7za e "*.7z" -so 2> /dev/null | split -l500000 --additional-suffix=".txt" --numeric-suffixes=1 - "file"
```

---

-- **`7za`** options:

- `e` - extract/decompress archive(s)
- `-so` - write the content to STDOUT

---

-- **`split`** options:

- `--additional-suffix=".txt"` - append suffix `.txt` to all resulting filenames
- `--numeric-suffixes=1` - use numeric suffixes starting at `1`
- `-` (hyphen) - read data from STDIN (standard input)
- `"file"` - the common prefix for all resulting filenames

---

The above command will result to files with the following naming format: `file01.txt`, `file02.txt` etc.

Comment: It's a detail, but won't `"*.7z"` produce `file-1.txt file-2.txt file.txt`, i.e. the wrong order?

Answer (score 1):

You could use pipes and the `--filter` option of `split` after decompression:

```
p7zip -d *.txt.7z
cat file.txt file-1.txt file-2.txt | split -l 500000 --filter='> $FILE.txt'
rm file*
```

Here is the documentation for the `--filter option`:

```
‘--filter=COMMAND’
     With this option, rather than simply writing to each output file,
     write through a pipe to the specified shell COMMAND for each output
     file.  COMMAND should use the $FILE environment variable, which is
     set to a different output file name for each invocation of the
     command.  For example, imagine that you have a 1TiB compressed file
     that, if uncompressed, would be too large to reside on disk, yet
     you must split it into individually-compressed pieces of a more
     manageable size.  To do that, you might run this command:

          xz -dc BIG.xz | split -b200G --filter='xz > $FILE.xz' - big-

     Assuming a 10:1 compression ratio, that would create about fifty
     20GiB files with names ‘big-aa.xz’, ‘big-ab.xz’, ‘big-ac.xz’, etc.
```

If you need to keep a file with all the output, you could use `tee`, which copies standard input to standard output and to the file given as argument.

```
cat file.txt file-1.txt file-2.txt |
    tee all.txt |
    split -l 50000 --filter='> $FILE.txt'
```

Comment: Why do you need `--filter` when you have [`--additional-suffix`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74166/22142) ?