# how to split the matching file pattern files in same directory using if else or for loop condition?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am having 5 types of files in same dirctory.then i want to split all the files in the same directory and i need to give the splitted file name as dynamic(original file name + additional extexnsion). File names like(K_MOSTLY*,L_MOSTLY*,M_MOSTLY*,IPBAR*).But i was able to split first matching files only not split second matching files.

```
for entry in /path/ ;
do
  split -b 700K K_MOSTLY* -d --additional-suffix K_MOSTLY*
  split -b 700K L_MOSTLY* -d --additional-suffix L_MOSTLY*
  split -b 700K M_MOSTLY* -d --additional-suffix M_MOSTLY*
  split -l22000 IPBAR -d --additional-suffix IPBARCODES*
  rm K_MOSTLY*
  rm L_MOSTLY*
  rm M_MOSTLY*
  rm IPBARCODES*
done
```

Comment: What is your intention with `K_MOSTLY*`?  Do you want that as the literal suffix on your files? Also, for the `split` command, options come first, then the filename, and last an optional prefix.  See the `split` manual.

Comment: i want to split the all the files in same folder. Filenames like "K_MOSTLY*.*" ..but i could't split the next files in the folder.

Comment: I lack an example of what files you have, what you are expecting to get, and what is actually happening.

Comment: check here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32626/split-a-file-by-line-and-have-control-over-resulting-files-extension

Comment: I am having 5 types of files in same dirctory.then i want to split all the files in the same directory and i need to give the splitted file name as dynamic(original file name + additional extexnsion).

Comment: I am having 5 types of files in same dirctory.then i want to split all the files in the same directory and i need to give the splitted file name as dynamic(original file name + additional extexnsion). File names like(K_MOSTLY*,L_MOSTLY*,M_MOSTLY*,IPBAR*).But i was able to split first matching files only not split second matching files.

Comment: this is i have used scripts:for entry in /path/ ;
do
split -b 700K K_MOSTLY* -d --additional-suffix K_MOSTLY*
split -b 700K L_MOSTLY* -d --additional-suffix L_MOSTLY*
split -b 700K M_MOSTLY* -d --additional-suffix M_MOSTLY*
split -l22000 IPBAR -d --additional-suffix IPBARCODES*
rm K_MOSTLY*
rm L_MOSTLY*
rm M_MOSTLY*
rm IPBARCODES*
done

Comment: how to do above one anyone pls help.

Comment: @steeldriver is it k?

Comment: @logeshwaran yes, thank you

Comment: @Kusalananda...did you have any idea bro?

Answer (score 0):

As @Kusalananda says, it's all in the `man` pages and your syntax is wrong.

That said, your question isn't clear but something along these line should do if you modify the prefix (`${f%.*}` and `IPBAR`) and suffix (`.${f##*.}`) to suit. Be careful of keeping the path intact in the destination filename.

```
p="./split/"
for f in ${p}[K-M]_MOSTLY* ${p}IPBARCODES*; do
  case "$f" in 
    *IPBARCODES*)
      split -l 2200 -d "$f" "${p}IPBAR" --additional-suffix=".${f##*.}"
      ;; 
    *[K-M]_MOSTLY*)
      split -b 700 -d "$f" "${f%.*}" --additional-suffix=".${f##*.}"
    ;;
  esac
  rm "$f"
done;
```

This takes

```
Banana.xml
IPBARCODES.xml
K_MOSTLY.xml
L_MOSTLY.xml
M_MOSTLY.xml
```

and gives

```
Banana.xml
IPBAR00.xml
IPBAR01.xml
K_MOSTLY00.xml
K_MOSTLY01.xml
L_MOSTLY00.xml
L_MOSTLY01.xml
M_MOSTLY00.xml
M_MOSTLY01.xml
```

Comment: @Kusalananda i have one more doubt.

Comment: @Kusalananda why the second new.source*.unl.Z file was not splitting?

Comment: @Kusalananda this is my scripts:cd /home/kron
path="/home/kron/"
for var1 in "$path"T_KI*
do
split -b 700K $var1 --additional-suffix="$(basename $var1)"
done
for var2 in "$path"madrid_styles*.unl.Z
do
if [ -f new.source*.unl.Z ]; then
gunzip /home/kron/new.source*.unl.Z
split -l11000 new.source*.unl --additional-suffix="$(basename $var2)"
else
exit 0
fi
done

Comment: cd /home/kron
path="/home/kron/"
for var1 in "$path"T_KI*
do
split -b 700K $var1 --additional-suffix="$(basename $var1)"
done
for var2 in "$path"madrid_styles*.unl.Z
do
if [ -f new.source*.unl.Z ]; then
gunzip /home/kron/new.source*.unl.Z
split -l11000 new.source*.unl --additional-suffix="$(basename $var2)"
else
exit 0
fi
done